# Regular Expression for Parsing Hashtags in Java

Tags: java, regex, twitter

Here is the Twitter message I am trying to parse (as you can see, some of these are not tags, just part of URLs):

```
#anothertag Arrogance and bad PR http://www.adobe.com/index.html#anchor1. John 
Nack on &#Adobe: Information about Photoshop&#169; CS3 on Snow Leopard 
#fail #design</pre>
```

This regular expression is what I have so far, but it still picks up some the url tags:

```
[##]+([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)
```

Comment: So what exactly are you trying to get? Can you provide expected result?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear. I am trying to do a match to find what are all the tags in a given tweet. I would expect that the tweet from above would return 'anothertag', 'fail' and 'design'.

Comment: Did you try this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563844/best-hashtag-regex/5768660#5768660

The regex arcain provides is based on Twitter's code and if I'm reading it right it ensures that the message does not begin with a hashtag. If you wanted to disable that you could remove the first parenthesized group. Should mention that I haven't tested this regex personally though :)

Comment: there's a much better answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4984806/java-regex-extract-hashtags-from-string

Answer (score 6):

Isn't it ironic, as soon as I post this I find an answer. So if you are looking for a matching pattern to do this, the following seems to work:

(?:\s|\A)[##]+([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)

I am going to do a lot more testing with this to see if there are any edge cases that are outside the scope of this expression and will report back if I find any.

Comment: (?:\s|\A|^)[##]+([A-Za-z0-9-_]+) also accepts a hashtag at the very beginning of the tweet

Answer (score 3):

I think this

```
(\s|\A)#(\w+)
```

works as well and is a little more precise. 
BTW, when working with Java regular expressions I always use [regexplanet](http://www.regexplanet.com/simple/index.jsp) to test my expressions. Much faster than testing in Java.

--Hardy

Answer (score 3):

@Daniel Dura: [##] this is supposed to be pointless. The brackets [] are used to denote character classes. [##] is same as [#]. And [##]+ is same as [#]+ .