# Best HashTag Regex

Tags: .net, regex, twitter

I'm trying to find all the hash tags in a string. The hashtags are from a stream like twitter, they could be anywhere in the text like:

> this is a #awesome event, lets use the
>   tag #fun

I'm using the .NET framework (c#), I was thinking this would be a suitable regex pattern to use:

#\w+

Is this the best regex for this purpose?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It depends on whether you want to match hashtags inside other strings ("Some#Word") or things that probably aren't hashtags ("We're #1").  The regex you gave `#\w+` will match in both these cases.  If you slightly modify your regex to `\B#\w\w+`, you can eliminate these cases and only match hashtags of length greater than 1 on word boundaries.

Comment: Thanks for that, I was a little worried the edge cases would cause me some grief.

Comment: Another note, this regex won't match "#tags-with-hyphens", so keep that in mind...

Comment: Maybe `\b[^ .,)\]}]` would be a better choice. But that still requires a word character (letter/number, iirc) at the beginning for `\b` to work. I have absolutely no clue how "hashtags" are used on Twitter, though. Might be that I'm gravely mistaken here and that they regularly include punctuation except hyphens.

Comment: `\b#` will only match if the `#` **is** immediately preceded by a word character.  If anything, you want the opposite: `\B#` (`\B` == "a position that is not a word boundary").

Comment: Spot on @Alan Moore .  The answer marked correct here isn't actually correct, it should be `\B#\w\w+'`.

Comment: I use this one to match words with accents (you can add any other sign you need): \B#([\wàâêëéèîïôûùüç]+)

Comment: Edit answer to reflect comments, checked implementation. Thanks @alan-moore.

Answer (score 39):

If you are pulling statuses containing hashtags from Twitter, you no longer need to find them yourself.  You can now specify the **include_entities** parameter to have Twitter automatically call out mentions, links, and hashtags.

For example, take the following call to [statuses/show](http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/statuses/show/:id):

http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/show/60183527282577408.json?include_entities=true

In the resultant JSON, notice the **entities** object.

```
"entities":{"urls":[{"expanded_url":null,"indices":[68,88],"url":"http:\/\/bit.ly\/gWZmaJ"}],"user_mentions":[],"hashtags":[{"text":"wordpress","indices":[89,99]}]}
```

You can use the above to locate the specific entities in the tweet (which occur between the string positions denoted by the **indices** property) and transform them appropriately.

If you just need the regular expression to locate the hashtags, Twitter provides these in an [open source library](https://blog.twitter.com/2010/introducing-the-open-source-twitter-text-libraries).

### Hashtag Match Pattern

```
(^|[^&\p{L}\p{M}\p{Nd}_\u200c\u200d\ua67e\u05be\u05f3\u05f4\u309b\u309c\u30a0\u30fb\u3003\u0f0b\u0f0c\u00b7])(#|\uFF03)(?!\uFE0F|\u20E3)([\p{L}\p{M}\p{Nd}_\u200c\u200d\ua67e\u05be\u05f3\u05f4\u309b\u309c\u30a0\u30fb\u3003\u0f0b\u0f0c\u00b7]*[\p{L}\p{M}][\p{L}\p{M}\p{Nd}_\u200c\u200d\ua67e\u05be\u05f3\u05f4\u309b\u309c\u30a0\u30fb\u3003\u0f0b\u0f0c\u00b7]*)
```

The above pattern can be pieced together from [this](https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text/blob/master/java/src/main/java/com/twitter/twittertext/Regex.java) java file (retrieved 2015-11-23). Validation tests for this pattern are located in [this file](https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text/blob/master/conformance/autolink.yml#L128) around line 128.

Comment: The link to the Twitter engineering page is broken.

Comment: The above pattern can be pieced together from [this](https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text/blob/master/java/src/com/twitter/Regex.java) java file. Validation tests for this pattern are located in [this](https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text/blob/master/conformance/autolink.yml#L120) file around line 120.

Comment: @Αλεχει - thanks! I updated the links in the answer with the latest ones you provided.

Answer (score 30):

After looking at the previous answers here and making some test tweets to see what Twitter liked, I think I've come up with a solid regular expression that should do the trick. It requires lookaround functionality in the regular expression engine, so it might not work with all engines out there. It should still work fine for .NET and PCRE.

```
(?:(?<=\s)|^)#(\w*[A-Za-z_]+\w*)
```

According to RegexBuddy, this does the following:
[image: RegexBuddy Create View]

And again, according to RegexBuddy, here is what it matches:
[image: RegexBuddy Test View]

Anything highlighted is part of the match. The darker highlighted part indicates what is returned from the capture.

**Edit Dec 2014:**
Here's a slightly simplified version from zero323 that should be functionally equivalent:

```
(?<=\s|^)#(\w*[A-Za-z_]+\w*)
```

Comment: This is a much better solution to the problem given.

Comment: Is there any particular reason for using `(?:(?<=\s)|^)` instead of `(?<=\s|^)`?

Comment: @zero323 Not that I can remember, no. I wrote this while learning regular expressions so I may have been overly verbose when I didn't need to.

Answer (score 5):

I tweeted a string with randomly placed hash tags, saw what Twitter did with it, and then tried to match it with a regular expression.  Here's what I got:

\B#\w*[a-zA-Z]+\w*

**#face** ***#Fa***!ce something **#iam**#1 #1 #919 **#jifdosaj** somethin#idfsjoa 9#9#98 9#9f9j#9jlasdjl **#jklfdsajl34** #34239 **#jkf** **#a** ***#1j3rj3**

Comment: Your case doesn't support #onetag#secondtag. This shouldn't be a hashtag.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, this pattern works the best. The others posted here don't take into account that a hashtag starting with numbers is invalid. Please ensure that you only use the second capturing group when you extract the hashtag.

```
(^|\s)#([A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]*)
```

Note, I've also explicitly limited lookaheads and lookbehinds because of their performance penalties.

[image]

Comment: I up-voted this for not requiring look-behinds and being pretty straight-forward on the pattern match.

Comment: This won't catch extended characters such as ñ and ō.

Answer (score 1):

this is what I use:

```
/#(\w*[0-9a-zA-Z]+\w*[0-9a-zA-Z])/g
```

[link of the hashtag Regex to test](https://regex101.com/r/pI7hE4/5)

[image: CavalcanteLeo]

Answer (score 0):

this is the one i wrote it looks for word boundaries and only matches hash text `(?<=#)\w*?(?=\W)`.

Answer (score 0):

`/#((\w|[\u00C0-\uFFDF])+)/g`

reference: [Unicode Table](http://www.tamasoft.co.jp/en/general-info/unicode.html)

Answer (score -1):

I've tested some tweets, and realized that hashtags:

- Are composed by alphanumeric characters plus underscore.
- Must have at least 1 letter or underscore.
- May have the dot character, but the hashtag will be interpreted as a link to an external site. (I do not consider this)

So, that's what I've got:

```
\B#(\w*[A-Za-z_]+\w*)
```

Comment: That will match "&#foobar" which Twitter doesn't consider to be a hashtag.

Comment: and don't match some langauge, like #déjà