# Deal with '#' through regex

Tags: c#, regex, twitter

Quick question , I have been trying to match any word containing a '#' from a string list and remove it, but I don't know how to handle it . been playing around on http://regexhero.net/tester/ trying but to no avail.

Essentially if it comes across #ff or wha#s up i will just regex.replace them.

any ideas on the Regular expression to use?.

Thanks.

Comment: You forgot to explain how the input looks like (list of words? of strings?), and what the output should look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563844/best-hashtag-regex/5768660#5768660) that covers some hashtag matching approaches.

In summary, if you are pulling statuses containing hashtags from Twitter, you no longer need to find them yourself.  You can now specify the **include_entities** parameter to have Twitter automatically call out mentions, links, and hashtags (if the method you are calling, like [statuses/show](http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/statuses/show/:id) supports this parameter.

If you just need the regular expression to locate the hashtags and capture it's elements, Twitter provides it in an [open source library](http://engineering.twitter.com/2010/02/introducing-open-source-twitter-text.html) that contains the following pattern.

```
(^|[^0-9A-Z&/]+)(#|\uFF03)([0-9A-Z_]*[A-Z_]+[a-z0-9_\\u00c0-\\u00d6\\u00d8-\\u00f6\\u00f8-\\u00ff]*)
```

More detail and additional links are provided in the original answer.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use regex - just use string.replace - it's a lot faster.

Answer (score 0):

So you're trying to remove any words containing a `#`?

If so, give this a try...

```
\w*#\w*
```

And replace with nothing, like so...

http://regexhero.net/tester/?id=cda1e713-bdab-4aa2-b63d-a87e9b2c9bce

`apple# orange ban#ana` becomes `orange`

---

But if you're simply trying to remove all instances of `#`, then String.Replace is the better choice.  `myString = myString.Replace("#", "");`