# How to remove # from Twitter hashtags?

Tags: php, regex

I want to strip off the # from twitter hash-tags, so:

```
Input: I love #winter and #ice-skating
Output: I love winter and ice-skating
```

I thought this would do the trick, but it doesn't:

```
$tweet = preg_replace('/#[^\s]*/i', '${1}', $tweet);
```

Could somebody explain to me why not? What should I change?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to surround the part you want to capture in parentheses:

```
$tweet = preg_replace('/#([\w-]+)/i', '$1', $tweet);
```

See it working online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/M4dSx)

I also changed the regular expression to be more specific, but for an even better regular expression I refer you to this question and its answers (for .NET but the idea is the  same in PHP):

- [Best HashTag Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563844/best-hashtag-regex)

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but in "Order#12" #12 wouldn't be a hashtag. This regex would replace #12 with 12 even so. Although this probably won't happen very much, for thoroughness I would include a lookbehind to check for a space or the beginning of the string.

Answer (score 5):

Faster solution:

```
$tweet = str_replace('#', '', $tweet)
```

No regex required

Comment: True to that, but it may be enough ;) when not Reveller should use yours or @MarkBayers solution

Answer (score 3):

1. You need to have a sub-pattern to match the string without the pound sign
2. Don't wrap `1` in the replacement string with curly braces

```
$tweet = preg_replace('/#([^\s]*)/', '$1', $tweet);
```