# how to separate numerous hashtags onto a separate page of a user post?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, hashtag

On my website, I allow users to make a post

This is what the current Post create controller looks like

```
     def create
      @post = current_user.posts.build(params[:post])
    if @post.save
      flash[:success] = "Posted!"
      redirect_to home_path
    else
      @feed_items = []
      render 'static_pages/home'
    end
  end
```

I would like to create a new page called "browse" and I want to list all of the hashtags in descending order. These hashtags will be pulled from the above posts. What is the best way to pull the hashtags (could be 1 or 2+ hashtags used in a single post) and display them in this new browse page?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression to pull hashtags out of text. There's a thread here: [Best HashTag Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563844/best-hashtag-regex) That post is about .NET, but regular expressions are pretty universal, so you should be able to use something there. (I recommend [Rubular](http://rubular.com/) for testing regular expressions). This one seems popular:

```
hashtag_regex = /\b#\w\w+/
```

Now, you have a choice about when  you pull the hashtags out in this way:

**Option One**

You can pull them out 'in real time', when the user loads the Browse page. This will probably be simpler to code, but is less flexible - you probably wouldn't be able to do things like search for posts by hashtag, or count the number of appearances of a particular hashtag. In this case, you can extract the hashtags in the view rendered by the Browse page, for instance, something like this:

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  Text: <%= post.text %>. Hashtags: <%= post.text.scan(hashtag_regex).join(',') %>
<% end %>
```

**Option Two**

You can extract hashtags when the Post is created/edited, and store them, either in a new field on the Post model, or in an associated model (Post `has_many :hashtags`), something like this:

```
def create
  @post = current_user.posts.build(params[:post])
  @post.hashtags = @post.text.scan(hashtag_regex)
```

Or as a callback on the post model:

```
class Post < AR:B
  before_save :extract_hashtags

  def extract_hashtags
    hashtags = text.scan(hashtag_regex)
  end
end
```

Then simply display them:

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  Text: <%= post.text %>. Hashtags: <%= post.hashtags %>
<% end %>
```

This approach is probably slightly more efficient, and by placing the hashtags in your database in their own field or table, you'll have the ability to sort by them, search for them, or count them.

I hope this is helpful.

Comment: Thanks! I'm probably going to go with the second option. I don't want to display `post.text`, just `post.hashtags`. Is it possible to use `("created_at desc")` on these hashtags and have them sorted by dates?

Comment: If you go with the associated model option (creating a `Hashtag` model), then you can have a `created_at` date for each instance of them (would have, by default, actually). If you go with the 'field on the Post model' option, you could hack up something that uses the `created_at` or `updated_at` fields of the Post, but I'm not sure if that would be accurate enough for your purposes.

Comment: one last question, are you familiar with the `Twitter-Text-Rb Gem`? Do you know if it's something that would be useful for my case?

Comment: Sorry, no, I haven't used that gem. Its description does suggest it would address your needs. On the other hand, it might be overkill if you're just extracting hashtags and nothing else.

Comment: when I create the hashtag model and table, what kind of fields/attributes should it have?

Comment: Well, it should have a string or text field for the hashtag, and a `post_id` to associate it with the post it comes from. It'll come with timestamps by default.