# PHP Regex - Finding multiple word start with # like '#ball'

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to create a PHP REGEX that will match if any word start with '#' like '#ball'. I have tried with this

```
preg_match_all('/( #\w+)/u', $text, $matches);
```

but it returns all words containing '#' like 'pin#ball'.

Comment: Google 'hashtag regexp' - fist resut: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563844/best-hashtag-regex It's .NET but hey its RegExp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$sData = '#pin all#foo #bar';
preg_match_all('/(^|\s+)#([a-zA-Z]+)/', $sData , $rgMatches);
//var_dump($rgMatches[2]);
```

Comment: You need to use `preg_match_all` to capture all the matches.

Comment: just /#[a-zA-Z]+/ to remove the preceding spaces

Comment: @VictorStanciu - thanks. Did not noticed that before. Edited.

Comment: thanks for replay.please see here if i use this string '#Invention requires a long-term willingness to be misunderstood," says Bezos. #quotes Read more: '. it return only '#quotes'. but i need '#quotes' and '#Invention ' both. i have used your code as {preg_match_all('/\s+#[a-zA-Z]+/', $text , $matches);} here $text is my string and $matches is an array.

Comment: @user2688482 - I've tried, it works well on your sample - notice `(^|\s+)` in my regex

Comment: @user2688482 make sure you use @Alma Do Mundo's latest version of the code. It covers the case when the text starts with a `#`.

Comment: thanks Alma Do Mundo.

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex.

```
preg_match_all('/(?!\b\s*)#.*\b/', $text, $matches);
```