# Making hash tags into links without ruining links that use the hash symbol

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

I have a post system that I'd like to have support both links and hash tags. The problem is that some links contain a #, themselves, and the code tries to convert the # in the link to more links!

A user might post "`http://somelink.com#hashKeyword #hashtag`"

Here is the code I'm working with. I believe it works, except for when links contain hashtags.

```
$theText = "http://somelink.com#hashKeyword #hashtag";

//Convert links
$reg_exUrl = "/(http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/";
if(preg_match($reg_exUrl, $theText, $url)) {
   $theText = preg_replace($reg_exUrl, '<a href="'.$url[0].'">'.$url[0].'</a>', $theText);
}

//Convert hash tags
$theText = preg_replace("/#(\w+)/", '<a href="linktohashtag/#$1">#$1</span>', $theText);
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Add a wordboundary `\b` before `#`.

Comment: Your regex `(http|https|ftp|ftps)://[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(/\S*)?` won't match the hashtag in your sample text because there isn't a provision to match it.

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: Thanks @HamZa, you're on the right track! I've answered my question below by expanding that idea.

Also, @sln it does, because `(/\S*)?` takes care of the symbols.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using [HamZa's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27582890/making-hash-tags-links-without-ruining-links-with-the-hash-symbol#comment43590385_27582890) and an [answer on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27283142/1117908), I was able to fix the issue.

I simply formatted the hashtag regex to only find tags that are after a space or the beginning of the post. That way, they don't conflict with the normal links.

`/(^|\s)#([A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]*)/`

Here's the new last line of code:

`$theText = preg_replace("/(^|\s)#([A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]*)/", '$1<a href="linktohashtag/#$2">#$2</span>', $theText);`

It works great! Thank you all for the discussion!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're trying to get two different results with one formula, i.e. X = 1, X = 2... however X cannot equal both 1 and 2 at the same time. You need to make a choice and implement something different.

Generally a `#` in a URL will try to find an element within the HTML dom that contains a matching id attribute. So `http://www.example.com/index.php#who-are-we` would open the index page and then shift the browser view to the element `<h1 id="who-are-we">`. That could be any HTML element, I've just used a h1 for this example.

With regards to creating links on your site you may wish to create a script which parses them, making them URL friendly. So if the post title is `How to work with twitter #hashtags`, your script would replace spaces with hyphens, and strip everything non-alphanumerics or a space. So you get a link like `how-to-work-with-twitter-hashtags`.