# Which characters are allowed in hashtags

Tags: regex, validation, twitter, hashtag

I am having a really hard time figuring out a regular expression (in C#) to validate hashtags. `\w` simply isn't enough as special characters are missing (ä, ö, ø, æ, å for starters, but also a lot of other foreign characters.

I need to support ALL hashtags there is. Mainly from Twitter, but in the future also from other providers.

My best shot (so far) is: `^#[a-zA-Z_0-9\u00C0-\u02AF]+$` (C# regex)

I cannot find any decent documentation from Twitter or anyone else about this, so:

- Does anyone know of any documentation I have missed?
- OR does anyone know which unicode ranges I should include as valid characters for hashtags?
- AND Can anybody tell me if there is a difference between the support of hashtags on e.g. Twitter, Instagram, Facebook, etc.?

**Update**
I should note that C# is not the only language I need this in. Thus the need for precise specification.

Comment: There is an answer here which I think is very exhaustive.: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563844/best-hashtag-regex

Comment: For Twitter hashtags, `@\w+` is enough. If you are using C# and need to match all Unicode letters, that is what `\w` matches (all `łóżźагорпл`, etc)

Comment: Just to illustrate: [`@\w+`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%40%5cw%2b&i=%40%c3%a4%c3%b6%c3%b8%c3%a6%c3%a5)

Comment: @Wiktor First of all that does not answer my questions. Secondly, can you guarantee that there will be no false positives? However, it is clear to me that I need to clarify that C# is not the only language I need this in.

Comment: @ceekays Thank you. I will look into it and close this one if it provides useful.

Comment: See https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text/blob/master/java/tests/com/twitter/RegexTest.java. In my comment, I confused `#` with `@`. And https://shkspr.mobi/blog/2010/02/hashtag-standards/. You cannot have a single regex for all regex flavors that will work well. You have to adjust for each language.

Comment: Yes indeed I have to adjust for each language. That is why knowing the unicode ranges would be a tremendous help, as it would allow me to implement the regex similarly in many languages.

Comment: Could you please let know what languages do you need to cover?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Primarily C# and Javascript, but possibly also some Python. The Java library you link to seems nice. I'd wish there was a C# implementation.

Comment: @beruic: I believe my regex below is very close, at least, it passes all the test cases specified in that Java project. In JavaScript, just use the character classes I provided below. When building a dynamic regex from these classes, use double escapes. And no need to use a specific class for `\s` in JS, as it already covers all Unicode whitespace.

Comment: In Python, the best way is to use Python 3 with the PyPi `regex` module that supports `\p{L}` and other Unicode category classes. Python 3 handles Unicode much better than Python 2 in general.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## A Quick-and-Dirty Simplified Approach

Here is a [nice-read from Twitter eng team](https://shkspr.mobi/blog/2010/02/hashtag-standards/):

> To be fair, the Twitter team do have a standard.  Even if they don't use it themselves.

The test cases and other valuable information is located at https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text/blob/master/java/src/test/java/com/twitter/twittertext/RegexTest.java. Acc. to it, the valid hashtag can be written in C# as

```
(^|\s)([#＃][\w\u05be\u05f3\u05f4]*[\p{L}_]+[\w\u05be\u05f3\u05f4]*)
```

See [this regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%5E%7C%5Cs)(%5B%23%EF%BC%83%5D%5B%5Cw%5Cu05be%5Cu05f3%5Cu05f4%5D*%5B%5Cp%7BL%7D_%5D%2B%5B%5Cw%5Cu05be%5Cu05f3%5Cu05f4%5D*)&i=%23hashtag%0D%0A%23Az%C9%99rbaycanca%0D%0A%23m%C3%BB%C7%81ae%0D%0A%23%C4%8Ce%C5%A1tina%0D%0A%23%C4%8Aaoi%E1%B9%81%C3%ADn%0D%0A%23Caoi%E1%B9%81%C3%ADn%0D%0A%23ta%CC%81im%0D%0A%23hag%CC%83ua%0D%0A%23caf%C3%A9%0D%0A%23%D7%A2%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%AA%20%2F%2F%20%22Hebrew%22%0D%0A%23%D7%90%D6%B2%D7%A9%D6%B6%D7%81%D7%A8%20%2F%2F%20with%20marks%0D%0A%23%D7%A2%D6%B7%D7%9C%D6%BE%D7%99%D6%B0%D7%93%D6%B5%D7%99%20%2F%2F%20with%20maqaf%2005be%0D%0A%23%D7%95%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%B3%20%2F%2F%20with%20geresh%2005f3%0D%0A%23%D7%9E%D7%B4%D7%9B%20%2F%2F%20with%20gershayim%2005f4%0D%0A%23%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B9%D8%B1%D8%A8%D9%8A%D8%A9%20%2F%2F%20%22Arabic%22%0D%0A%23%D8%AD%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%8A%D8%A7%D9%8B%20%2F%2F%20with%20mark%0D%0A%23%D9%8A%D9%80%EF%AE%B1%D9%80%D9%8E%D9%B1%20%2F%2F%20with%20pres.%20form%0D%0A%23%E0%B8%9B%E0%B8%A3%E0%B8%B0%E0%B9%80%E0%B8%97%E0%B8%A8%E0%B9%84%E0%B8%97%E0%B8%A2%0D%0A%23%E0%B8%9F%E0%B8%A3%E0%B8%B5%20%2F%2F%20with%20mark%0D%0A%23%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E8%AA%9E%E3%83%8F%E3%83%83%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A5%E3%82%BF%E3%82%B0%0D%0A%EF%BC%83%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E8%AA%9E%E3%83%8F%E3%83%83%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A5%E3%82%BF%E3%82%B0%0D%0A%E3%81%93%E3%82%8C%E3%81%AFOK%20%23%E3%83%8F%E3%83%83%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A5%E3%82%BF%E3%82%B0%0D%0A%E3%81%93%E3%82%8C%E3%82%82OK%E3%80%82%23%E3%83%8F%E3%83%83%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A5%E3%82%BF%E3%82%B0%0D%0AFALSE%0D%0A%E3%81%93%E3%82%8C%E3%81%AF%E3%83%80%E3%83%A1%23%E3%83%8F%E3%83%83%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A5%E3%82%BF%E3%82%B0%0D%0A%231%0D%0A%232)

Since you want to be able to use this in any language, just note that `\p{L}` is equal to

```
[A-Za-z\xAA\xB5\xBA\xC0-\xD6\xD8-\xF6\xF8-\u02C1\u02C6-\u02D1\u02E0-\u02E4\u02EC\u02EE\u0370-\u0374\u0376\u0377\u037A-\u037D\u037F\u0386\u0388-\u038A\u038C\u038E-\u03A1\u03A3-\u03F5\u03F7-\u0481\u048A-\u052F\u0531-\u0556\u0559\u0561-\u0587\u05D0-\u05EA\u05F0-\u05F2\u0620-\u064A\u066E\u066F\u0671-\u06D3\u06D5\u06E5\u06E6\u06EE\u06EF\u06FA-\u06FC\u06FF\u0710\u0712-\u072F\u074D-\u07A5\u07B1\u07CA-\u07EA\u07F4\u07F5\u07FA\u0800-\u0815\u081A\u0824\u0828\u0840-\u0858\u08A0-\u08B4\u0904-\u0939\u093D\u0950\u0958-\u0961\u0971-\u0980\u0985-\u098C\u098F\u0990\u0993-\u09A8\u09AA-\u09B0\u09B2\u09B6-\u09B9\u09BD\u09CE\u09DC\u09DD\u09DF-\u09E1\u09F0\u09F1\u0A05-\u0A0A\u0A0F\u0A10\u0A13-\u0A28\u0A2A-\u0A30\u0A32\u0A33\u0A35\u0A36\u0A38\u0A39\u0A59-\u0A5C\u0A5E\u0A72-\u0A74\u0A85-\u0A8D\u0A8F-\u0A91\u0A93-\u0AA8\u0AAA-\u0AB0\u0AB2\u0AB3\u0AB5-\u0AB9\u0ABD\u0AD0\u0AE0\u0AE1\u0AF9\u0B05-\u0B0C\u0B0F\u0B10\u0B13-\u0B28\u0B2A-\u0B30\u0B32\u0B33\u0B35-\u0B39\u0B3D\u0B5C\u0B5D\u0B5F-\u0B61\u0B71\u0B83\u0B85-\u0B8A\u0B8E-\u0B90\u0B92-\u0B95\u0B99\u0B9A\u0B9C\u0B9E\u0B9F\u0BA3\u0BA4\u0BA8-\u0BAA\u0BAE-\u0BB9\u0BD0\u0C05-\u0C0C\u0C0E-\u0C10\u0C12-\u0C28\u0C2A-\u0C39\u0C3D\u0C58-\u0C5A\u0C60\u0C61\u0C85-\u0C8C\u0C8E-\u0C90\u0C92-\u0CA8\u0CAA-\u0CB3\u0CB5-\u0CB9\u0CBD\u0CDE\u0CE0\u0CE1\u0CF1\u0CF2\u0D05-\u0D0C\u0D0E-\u0D10\u0D12-\u0D3A\u0D3D\u0D4E\u0D5F-\u0D61\u0D7A-\u0D7F\u0D85-\u0D96\u0D9A-\u0DB1\u0DB3-\u0DBB\u0DBD\u0DC0-\u0DC6\u0E01-\u0E30\u0E32\u0E33\u0E40-\u0E46\u0E81\u0E82\u0E84\u0E87\u0E88\u0E8A\u0E8D\u0E94-\u0E97\u0E99-\u0E9F\u0EA1-\u0EA3\u0EA5\u0EA7\u0EAA\u0EAB\u0EAD-\u0EB0\u0EB2\u0EB3\u0EBD\u0EC0-\u0EC4\u0EC6\u0EDC-\u0EDF\u0F00\u0F40-\u0F47\u0F49-\u0F6C\u0F88-\u0F8C\u1000-\u102A\u103F\u1050-\u1055\u105A-\u105D\u1061\u1065\u1066\u106E-\u1070\u1075-\u1081\u108E\u10A0-\u10C5\u10C7\u10CD\u10D0-\u10FA\u10FC-\u1248\u124A-\u124D\u1250-\u1256\u1258\u125A-\u125D\u1260-\u1288\u128A-\u128D\u1290-\u12B0\u12B2-\u12B5\u12B8-\u12BE\u12C0\u12C2-\u12C5\u12C8-\u12D6\u12D8-\u1310\u1312-\u1315\u1318-\u135A\u1380-\u138F\u13A0-\u13F5\u13F8-\u13FD\u1401-\u166C\u166F-\u167F\u1681-\u169A\u16A0-\u16EA\u16F1-\u16F8\u1700-\u170C\u170E-\u1711\u1720-\u1731\u1740-\u1751\u1760-\u176C\u176E-\u1770\u1780-\u17B3\u17D7\u17DC\u1820-\u1877\u1880-\u18A8\u18AA\u18B0-\u18F5\u1900-\u191E\u1950-\u196D\u1970-\u1974\u1980-\u19AB\u19B0-\u19C9\u1A00-\u1A16\u1A20-\u1A54\u1AA7\u1B05-\u1B33\u1B45-\u1B4B\u1B83-\u1BA0\u1BAE\u1BAF\u1BBA-\u1BE5\u1C00-\u1C23\u1C4D-\u1C4F\u1C5A-\u1C7D\u1CE9-\u1CEC\u1CEE-\u1CF1\u1CF5\u1CF6\u1D00-\u1DBF\u1E00-\u1F15\u1F18-\u1F1D\u1F20-\u1F45\u1F48-\u1F4D\u1F50-\u1F57\u1F59\u1F5B\u1F5D\u1F5F-\u1F7D\u1F80-\u1FB4\u1FB6-\u1FBC\u1FBE\u1FC2-\u1FC4\u1FC6-\u1FCC\u1FD0-\u1FD3\u1FD6-\u1FDB\u1FE0-\u1FEC\u1FF2-\u1FF4\u1FF6-\u1FFC\u2071\u207F\u2090-\u209C\u2102\u2107\u210A-\u2113\u2115\u2119-\u211D\u2124\u2126\u2128\u212A-\u212D\u212F-\u2139\u213C-\u213F\u2145-\u2149\u214E\u2183\u2184\u2C00-\u2C2E\u2C30-\u2C5E\u2C60-\u2CE4\u2CEB-\u2CEE\u2CF2\u2CF3\u2D00-\u2D25\u2D27\u2D2D\u2D30-\u2D67\u2D6F\u2D80-\u2D96\u2DA0-\u2DA6\u2DA8-\u2DAE\u2DB0-\u2DB6\u2DB8-\u2DBE\u2DC0-\u2DC6\u2DC8-\u2DCE\u2DD0-\u2DD6\u2DD8-\u2DDE\u2E2F\u3005\u3006\u3031-\u3035\u303B\u303C\u3041-\u3096\u309D-\u309F\u30A1-\u30FA\u30FC-\u30FF\u3105-\u312D\u3131-\u318E\u31A0-\u31BA\u31F0-\u31FF\u3400-\u4DB5\u4E00-\u9FD5\uA000-\uA48C\uA4D0-\uA4FD\uA500-\uA60C\uA610-\uA61F\uA62A\uA62B\uA640-\uA66E\uA67F-\uA69D\uA6A0-\uA6E5\uA717-\uA71F\uA722-\uA788\uA78B-\uA7AD\uA7B0-\uA7B7\uA7F7-\uA801\uA803-\uA805\uA807-\uA80A\uA80C-\uA822\uA840-\uA873\uA882-\uA8B3\uA8F2-\uA8F7\uA8FB\uA8FD\uA90A-\uA925\uA930-\uA946\uA960-\uA97C\uA984-\uA9B2\uA9CF\uA9E0-\uA9E4\uA9E6-\uA9EF\uA9FA-\uA9FE\uAA00-\uAA28\uAA40-\uAA42\uAA44-\uAA4B\uAA60-\uAA76\uAA7A\uAA7E-\uAAAF\uAAB1\uAAB5\uAAB6\uAAB9-\uAABD\uAAC0\uAAC2\uAADB-\uAADD\uAAE0-\uAAEA\uAAF2-\uAAF4\uAB01-\uAB06\uAB09-\uAB0E\uAB11-\uAB16\uAB20-\uAB26\uAB28-\uAB2E\uAB30-\uAB5A\uAB5C-\uAB65\uAB70-\uABE2\uAC00-\uD7A3\uD7B0-\uD7C6\uD7CB-\uD7FB\uF900-\uFA6D\uFA70-\uFAD9\uFB00-\uFB06\uFB13-\uFB17\uFB1D\uFB1F-\uFB28\uFB2A-\uFB36\uFB38-\uFB3C\uFB3E\uFB40\uFB41\uFB43\uFB44\uFB46-\uFBB1\uFBD3-\uFD3D\uFD50-\uFD8F\uFD92-\uFDC7\uFDF0-\uFDFB\uFE70-\uFE74\uFE76-\uFEFC\uFF21-\uFF3A\uFF41-\uFF5A\uFF66-\uFFBE\uFFC2-\uFFC7\uFFCA-\uFFCF\uFFD2-\uFFD7\uFFDA-\uFFDC]
```

and `\w` is a combination of `\p{L}`, `_` and a `\p{N}`, see `\p{N}` below:

```
[0-9\xB2\xB3\xB9\xBC-\xBE\u0660-\u0669\u06F0-\u06F9\u07C0-\u07C9\u0966-\u096F\u09E6-\u09EF\u09F4-\u09F9\u0A66-\u0A6F\u0AE6-\u0AEF\u0B66-\u0B6F\u0B72-\u0B77\u0BE6-\u0BF2\u0C66-\u0C6F\u0C78-\u0C7E\u0CE6-\u0CEF\u0D66-\u0D75\u0DE6-\u0DEF\u0E50-\u0E59\u0ED0-\u0ED9\u0F20-\u0F33\u1040-\u1049\u1090-\u1099\u1369-\u137C\u16EE-\u16F0\u17E0-\u17E9\u17F0-\u17F9\u1810-\u1819\u1946-\u194F\u19D0-\u19DA\u1A80-\u1A89\u1A90-\u1A99\u1B50-\u1B59\u1BB0-\u1BB9\u1C40-\u1C49\u1C50-\u1C59\u2070\u2074-\u2079\u2080-\u2089\u2150-\u2182\u2185-\u2189\u2460-\u249B\u24EA-\u24FF\u2776-\u2793\u2CFD\u3007\u3021-\u3029\u3038-\u303A\u3192-\u3195\u3220-\u3229\u3248-\u324F\u3251-\u325F\u3280-\u3289\u32B1-\u32BF\uA620-\uA629\uA6E6-\uA6EF\uA830-\uA835\uA8D0-\uA8D9\uA900-\uA909\uA9D0-\uA9D9\uA9F0-\uA9F9\uAA50-\uAA59\uABF0-\uABF9\uFF10-\uFF19]
```

and whitespace is something like

```
[\t\f\v\r\n\x20\xA0\u1680\u2000-\u200A\u2028\u2029\u202F\u205F\u3000]
```

Note there can be issues with diacritic matching in  ES5 regex syntax.

**UPDATE**

## [twitter-text](https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text) C# Adaptation

The Java library features the following regex for the hashtags:

```
VALID_HASHTAG = Pattern.compile("(^|[^&" + HASHTAG_LETTERS_NUMERALS + "])(#|\uFF03)(?!\uFE0F|\u20E3)(" + HASHTAG_LETTERS_NUMERALS_SET + "*" + HASHTAG_LETTERS_SET + HASHTAG_LETTERS_NUMERALS_SET + "*)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

Translating into C#:

```
string HASHTAG_LETTERS = @"\p{L}\p{M}";
string HASHTAG_NUMERALS = @"\p{Nd}";
string HASHTAG_SPECIAL_CHARS = @"_\u200c\u200d\ua67e\u05be\u05f3\u05f4\uff5e\u301c\u309b\u309c\u30a0\u30fb\u3003\u0f0b\u0f0c\u00b7";
string HASHTAG_LETTERS_NUMERALS = HASHTAG_LETTERS + HASHTAG_NUMERALS + HASHTAG_SPECIAL_CHARS;
string HASHTAG_LETTERS_NUMERALS_SET = "[" + HASHTAG_LETTERS_NUMERALS + "]";
string HASHTAG_LETTERS_SET = "[" + HASHTAG_LETTERS + "]";
string VALID_HASHTAG = new Regex("(^|[^&" + HASHTAG_LETTERS_NUMERALS + @"])(#|\uFF03)(?!\uFE0F|\u20E3)(" + HASHTAG_LETTERS_NUMERALS_SET + "*" + HASHTAG_LETTERS_SET + HASHTAG_LETTERS_NUMERALS_SET + "*)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

And here is a [testing C# demo](https://ideone.com/F7muLT):

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string HASHTAG_LETTERS = @"\p{L}\p{M}";
        string HASHTAG_NUMERALS = @"\p{Nd}";
        string HASHTAG_SPECIAL_CHARS = @"_\u200c\u200d\ua67e\u05be\u05f3\u05f4\uff5e\u301c\u309b\u309c\u30a0\u30fb\u3003\u0f0b\u0f0c\u00b7";
        string HASHTAG_LETTERS_NUMERALS = HASHTAG_LETTERS + HASHTAG_NUMERALS + HASHTAG_SPECIAL_CHARS;
        string HASHTAG_LETTERS_NUMERALS_SET = "[" + HASHTAG_LETTERS_NUMERALS + "]";
        string HASHTAG_LETTERS_SET = "[" + HASHTAG_LETTERS + "]";
        Regex VALID_HASHTAG = new Regex("(^|[^&" + HASHTAG_LETTERS_NUMERALS + @"])(#|\uFF03)(?!\uFE0F|\u20E3)(" + HASHTAG_LETTERS_NUMERALS_SET + "*" + HASHTAG_LETTERS_SET + HASHTAG_LETTERS_NUMERALS_SET + "*)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        
        List<string> tests = new List<string>() {"#hashtag",
            "#Azərbaycanca",
            "#mûǁae",
            "#Čeština",
            "#Ċaoiṁín",
            "#Caoiṁín",
            "#táim",
            "#hag̃ua",
            "#café",
            "#עברית",
            "#אֲשֶׁר",
            "#עַל־יְדֵי",
            "#וכו׳",
            "#מ״כ",
            "#العربية",
            "#حالياً",
            "#يـﮱـَٱ",
            "#ประเทศไทย",
            "#ฟรี",
            "#日本語ハッシュタグ",
            "＃日本語ハッシュタグ",
            "これはOK #ハッシュタグ",
            "これもOK。#ハッシュタグ",
            "これはダメ#ハッシュタグ",
            "#1",
            "#2"};
        tests.ForEach(input => // JUST A PIECE OF DEMO CODE
            Console.WriteLine("Input: " + input + " = " + VALID_HASHTAG.IsMatch(input) +
              (VALID_HASHTAG.IsMatch(input) ? ", match = " + VALID_HASHTAG.Match(input).Value : "")));
    }
}
```

## JavaScript Hashtag validation

If you use [JS Twitter library](https://cdn.rawgit.com/twitter/twitter-text/v1.13.4/js/twitter-text.js), identifying hasgtags can be done with a mere:

```
var isValidHashtag = twttr.txt.isValidHashtag(hashtag);
```

Comment: The first link is a good read presenting the problem, however not many answers.

Comment: I looked at https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text/blob/master/java/src/com/twitter/Regex.java and found out that their matcher is actually very easy to port to C# as the Regex is basically the same. Looking at this, it seems you lack a part right after the `#` in your solution.

Comment: Re Update: I did exactly the same, and is currently looking at https://cdn.rawgit.com/twitter/twitter-text/v1.13.4/js/twitter-text.js for a js solution. we are approaching an answer here.

Comment: Looks like you can just use that library, or you can build your own one using the blocks from either that library or `XRegExp` (the ones I provided in the answer).

Comment: Using https://cdn.rawgit.com/twitter/twitter-text/v1.13.4/js/twitter-text.js it's as simple as `twttr.txt.isValidHashtag(hashtag)`. Update your answer with this (and perhaps remove those ugly `var` declarations and replace them with `string`), and I'd say this answer will be good enough to be accepted.

Comment: [`var` is fully compliant with C# 3.0](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx).

Comment: I know. It's just ugly.

Comment: Oh, and please link to https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text in the answer to make it easy to find. It kinda seems like the only official source of how twitter does it. If no one else bids in with their take on hashtags, I'd say that Twitter gets the right to define.