# R: Regular Expression for Twitter hashtags?

Tags: r, regex

I'm trying to come up with a regular expression that matches Twitter hashtags. Twitter hashtags have the following rules:

1)They cannot contain spaces,

2)They cannot contain punctuation

3) They cannot start with or use only numbers.

This is what I've come up so far, but it still has issues with spaces and punctuation characters:

```
"#{1}[^0-9]*[^[::punct::]\\s]*?[A-z0-9]*?"
```

Would appreciate any help with this. Thanks!

Comment: This is most probably the definitive answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36895543/which-characters-are-allowed-in-hashtags (when you accept Twitter hashtags as authority)

Answer (score -1):

Your regex looks a bit complicated, you only need to match the `#` then a letter and then alphanumeric characters.

You also don't need quantifier for a single character. This should work:

```
#[a-zA-Z]\w*
```

If you won't allow underscores (they are legal characters in tweets), use this instead:

```
#[a-zA-Z][\da-zA-Z]*
```

It looks like the real spec for a hashtag however is that underscores and numbers are valid anywhere as long as they're at least a letter.

So this would be better:

```
#\w*[a-zA-Z]\w*
```

Comment: What is the point of the underscore?

Comment: It is a valid character for hashtags. It's also part of `\w`.

Comment: My bad, it looks like it can't be in first position either, deleted

Comment: You allow ponctuations like "/"

Comment: I tried here https://regex101.com/ and didn't find a way to match that character. How woul I do it ?

Comment: I mean, you do a match without them but you allow a match even if they are present and touching the word. I thought that this is what you were meaning by "This allow punctuation in second position".

Comment: Nope, what I meant is that any character besides a number can go just after the pound sign: `#!aoo` is matched by your regex

Comment: Could I do something like `(#[^0-9[::punct::]][\w]?)` ?

Comment: You're only matching 2 characters hashtags though, it would be better by replacing the final `?` with  `*`

Answer (score -1):

This regex captures only valid hashtags :

```
(#[a-zA-Z]+[\w]?)(?:\s|$)
```