# PHP : add a html tag around specifc words

Tags: php, html, css, regex, preg-replace

I have a data base with texts and in each text there are words (tags) that start with # (example of a record : "Hi I'm posting an #issue on #Stackoverflow ")

I'm trying to find a solution to add html code to transform each tag into a link when printing the text.

So the text are stored as strings in MySQL database like this :

Some text #tag1 text #tag2 ...

I want to replace all these #abcd with

```
<a href="targetpage.php?val=abcd">#abcd</a>
```

And have a final result as follow:

```
Some text <a href="targetpage.php?val=tag1">#tag1</a> text <a href="targetpage.php?val=tag2">#tag2</a> ...
```

I guess that i should use some regex but it is not at all my strong side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution could look like this:

```
$re = '/\S*#(\[[^\]]+\]|\S+)/m';
$str = 'Some text #tag1 text #tag2 ...';
$subst = '<a href="targetpage.php?val=$1">#$1</a>';

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
echo "The result of the substitution is ".$result;
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/PDGMQK/1)

If you are actually after Twitter hashtags and want to go crazy take a look [here](https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text/blob/master/java/src/test/java/com/twitter/twittertext/RegexTest.java) how it is done in Java.

There is also a [JavaScript Twitter library](https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text/tree/master/js) that makes things very easy.

Comment: If you want to go beyond that check-out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36902556/8291949).

Comment: Thank you very much. Looks good! I will try it and keep in touch with you!

Answer (score 2):

Try the following using `preg_replace(..)`

```
$input = "Hi I'm posting an #issue on #Stackoverflow";
echo preg_replace("/#([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/", "<a href='targetpage.php?val=$1'>#$1</a>", $input);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Comment: Add # with $1 variable before ending of anchor tag to match the requested output .

Answer (score 1):

Try this the function

```
<?php
  $demoString1 = "THIS is #test STRING WITH #abcd";
  $demoString2 = "Hi I'm posting an #issue on #Stackoverflow";

  function wrapWithAnchor($link,$string){
       $pattern = "/#([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/";
       $replace_with = '<a href="'.$link.'?val=$1">$1<a>';

       return preg_replace( $pattern, $replace_with ,$string ); 
 }

   $link= 'http://www.targetpage.php';
   echo wrapWithAnchor($link,$demoString1);
   echo '<hr />';
   echo wrapWithAnchor($link,$demoString2);

 ?>
```

[image]

[image]