# Regular expression to match hashtags in both English and Chinese

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm trying to write a regex to extract hashtag content in both English and Chinese. Hashtags in Chinese are indicated differently from hashtags in English. Two hashtag symbols are used, and the content is put right in between them, such as `#中国#`. Also, spaces are not used in Chinese. An example is

```
我来自#中国#。
```

The corresponding sentence in English is

```
I'm from #China.
```

Is it possible to write a single regex to extract hashtags in these two languages? If so, how?

Comment: Yes, where did you get stuck?

Comment: For Twitter-style hashtags see the official twitter-text library also available in ruby https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text/tree/master/rb and reference https://stackoverflow.com/a/36902556/8291949

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
string = "我来自#中国#。 I'm from #China."        
string.scan(/#\w+|#\p{Han}+#/)
=> ["#中国#", "#China"]
```