# spliting hashtags in a data.frame object with R

Tags: r, twitter, hashtag

I am collecting twitter's hashtags. Each tweet can include hashtags.

```
tests <- c("xxxxxx #SaveTheDate xxxxxx #Histoire] xxxxxx #Femmes xxxxxxx #ports",
       "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
       "xxxx #rock xxxxxx #Nantes" ,
       "xxxxxx #lvan xxxxxxx #nantes xxxxx #ilsepassetoujoursuntruc")


library (stringr)

hashtags <- str_extract_all(tests, "#\\S+")

str (hashtags)
```

Ma results:

```
 str(hashtags)  
 list of 4
 $ : chr [1:4] "#SaveTheDate" "#Histoire]" "#Femmes" "#ports"  
 $ : chr(0)  
 $ : chr [1:2] "#rock" "#Nantes"  
 $ : chr [1:3] "#lvan" "#nantes" "#ilsepassetoujoursuntruc"
```

What I expect: a data.frame with one hashtag for a row

```
 "#SaveTheDate" 
 "#Histoire"
 "#Femmes" 
  "#ports"
  NA
  ....
```

What I tried:

```
hashtags_df <-as.data.frame(hashtags)
```

Comment: how exactly was `as.data.frame()` supposed to divine your intentions? [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38788494/hashtag-extract-function-in-r-programming/38789142#38789142) may help with the hashtag recognition & extraction. I'm curious how you're going to deal with hashtag spam, hashtag pollution and hashtag abuse. 20-30% of your corpus will be littered with those.

Comment: I am working on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
hashtags[!lengths(hashtags)] <- NA
```

This will replace your length zero lists with NAs. (better solution for this via Dirty Sock Sniffer)

```
hashtags <- unlist(hashtags)
```

will give you a column vector of the values. If you'd like a dataframe, you can use as.data.frame now.

```
hashtags_df <- as.data.frame(hashtags)
```

I don't know the best way to extract hashtags, etc., but this should answer the question as currently asked.

Comment: Using `unlist` is what I’d do too, but it doesn’t match OP’s desired output exactly: you won’t get any `NA`s.

Comment: Ah, nice, thanks! I knew there was something simpler but I'm not super knowledgeable with that type of code.