# How to build a Corpus of hashtags (Text Mining)

Tags: r, text-mining, corpus, topic-modeling

I am trying to analyze a twitter data by mining all the hashtags. I want to put all hashtags in a corpus and mapping this corpus to a list of words. Do you have any idea how I can to manage this problem ? 
Here is a snap of my data

[image]

Here is the code that I used but I have a problem in my DTM with a 100% of sparsity

```
step1 <- strsplit(newFile$Hashtag, "#")
step2 <- lapply(step1, tail, -1)
result <- lapply(step2, function(x){
sapply(strsplit(x, " "), head, 1)
})
result2<-do.call(c, unlist(result, recursive=FALSE))
myCorpus <- tm::Corpus(VectorSource(result2)) # create a corpus
```

Here is information about my Corpus

```
myCorpus
  <<SimpleCorpus>>
 Metadata:  corpus specific: 1, document level (indexed): 0
 Content:  documents: 12635
```

And my DTM

```
<<DocumentTermMatrix (documents: 12635, terms: 6280)>>
Non-/sparse entries: 12285/79335515
Sparsity           : 100%
Maximal term length: 36
Weighting          : term frequency (tf)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Pictures aren't code or data unless it's a Q on image processing. You had guidance when creating a question and in the SO on how to make a decent question. We don't know how/what you twitter-searched for.  Thus, for your query, the hashtags may be sparse.  Also, hashtag "parsing" is [more complex than that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38789142/1457051)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is you are using `str_split`. You should try:

`str_extract_all("This all are hashtag #hello #I #am #a #buch #of #hashtags", "#\\S+")`

```
As results this list:
[[1]]
[1] "#hello"    "#I"        "#am"       "#a"        "#buch"     "#of"      
[7] "#hashtags"
```

If your desired result is a data frame use `simplify = T`:

```
str_extract_all("This all are hashtag #hello #I #am #a #buch #of #hashtags", "#\\S+", simplify = T)
```

As result:

```
     [,1]     [,2] [,3]  [,4] [,5]    [,6]  [,7]       
[1,] "#hello" "#I" "#am" "#a" "#buch" "#of" "#hashtags"
```