# .split() and .replace() a string value to filter out the desired text in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**I am trying to filter out the hashtags in a text string, by splitting it, and removing unwanted HTML tags**.

I'm not getting the correct output, and I am not too sure where I am making my mistake, and would appreciate your guidance.

**This is an example of the text string value:**

```
"<a href=\"https://twitter.com/search?q=fnb\" target=\"_blank\">#fnb</a>, <a href=\"https://twitter.com/search?q=mobilesimcard\" target=\"_blank\">#mobilesimcard</a>, <a href=\"https://twitter.com/search?q=what\" target=\"_blank\">#what</a>, <a href=\"https://twitter.com/search?q=refugeechild\" target=\"_blank\">#refugeechild</a>"
```

**This is the code I have thus far:**

```js
var str = "<a href=\"https://twitter.com/search?q=fnb\" target=\"_blank\">#fnb</a>, <a href=\"https://twitter.com/search?q=mobilesimcard\" target=\"_blank\">#mobilesimcard</a>, <a href=\"https://twitter.com/search?q=what\" target=\"_blank\">#what</a>, <a href=\"https://twitter.com/search?q=refugeechild\" target=\"_blank\">#refugeechild</a>";

var array = [];
var parts = str.split('target=\"_blank\">', '');

parts.forEach(function (part) {
 var rem1 = part.replace('</a>', '');
 array.push(rem1)
})
var value = array;
console.log(value);
```

**My desired output is: #fnb, #mobilesimcard, #what, #refugeechild**

My `str.split()` is not working correctly, and I believe I will have to expand on the `.replace()` as well.

Thank you!

Comment: why not use a Regular Expression? `str..match(/#[a-z-_]+/ig)` yields `["#fnb", "#mobilesimcard", "#what", "#refugeechild"]`

Comment: @MartinSchneider that looks great, and would work great! Can you perhaps share the full implementation with me?

Comment: just use it just like `var parts = str.match(/#[a-z-_]+/ig);`

Comment: If you want to work with html string, Regular Expression is a very powerful tool. And it also exists in many other useful tools. Instead of ask a certain question, why not start to learn it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution with a regular expression:

```
var str = "<a href=\"https://twitter.com/search?q=fnb\" target=\"_blank\">#fnb</a>, <a href=\"https://twitter.com/search?q=mobilesimcard\" target=\"_blank\">#mobilesimcard</a>, <a href=\"https://twitter.com/search?q=what\" target=\"_blank\">#what</a>, <a href=\"https://twitter.com/search?q=refugeechild\" target=\"_blank\">#refugeechild</a>";
var array = str.match(/#[a-z-_]+/ig)

console.log(array);
```

This regex is just a very simple one, there are tons better in the wild, like [Best HashTag Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563844/best-hashtag-regex#5768660)

Answer (score 1):

Try array [**map()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method **:**

**Working demo :**

```js
var str = "<a href=\"https://twitter.com/search?q=fnb\" target=\"_blank\">#fnb</a>, <a href=\"https://twitter.com/search?q=mobilesimcard\" target=\"_blank\">#mobilesimcard</a>, <a href=\"https://twitter.com/search?q=what\" target=\"_blank\">#what</a>, <a href=\"https://twitter.com/search?q=refugeechild\" target=\"_blank\">#refugeechild</a>";

var resArray = [];
var parts = str.split('</a>');

var array = parts.map(function(item) {
  return item.split('>')[1];
});

for(var i = 0; i < array.length-1; i++) {
  resArray.push(array[i]);
}

var value = resArray;
console.log(value);
```