# I want to add some html tag in string if specific substring found

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-standard

What i need is when user add message with hashtags, while display the message hashtags should look different.

In .Net, I have a string like

```
var stringVal = "Hello, #goodmorning, this is sample #cool text.";
```

I need to wrap hashtag value in  tag and get new string like

```
var resultString = "Hello <span style="color:blue;">#goodmorning</span>, this is sample <span style="color:blue;">#cool</span> text.";
```

Would you please help me with better option to do this?

I would appreciate your help. Thank You in advance.

Comment: And what if the string is like: 'He#llo, #goodmorning, this is sample #cool text##.' ? How do you define a 'hashtag' ?

Comment: Please share what you've tried so far?

Comment: String should start with # and then check for space or any other special character, the same like we have in social media.

Comment: I want to display hashtag different when we display message.

Comment: Probably you need to use regex in order to find hashtags in the specified string. Similar question has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563844/best-hashtag-regex?rq=1  Hope it will help. And in order to replace substrings you can use this Regex.Replace  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace?view=net-5.0

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the below code:

```
string str = "Hello #goodmoring! This is #nice.";
    
List<string> aLst = new List<string>(); 
    
foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(s, @"(?<!\w)#\w+")) //Using regex to check if any word starts with #
{
    aLst.Add(match.Value); //Adding to a list if found
}
    
foreach (var replacement in aLst)
{
    str = str.Replace(replacement, "<span style='color:blue;'>" + replacement + "</span>"); //Finally replacing the value starts with #
}
    
Console.WriteLine(str);
```

**Expected Output**:

```
Hello <span style='color:blue;'>#goodmoring</span>! This is <span style='color:blue;'>#nice</span>.
```

Comment: It will also replace the hashvalue which is under any url. Like if i have a string which has any url with some # value in it.