# Java Regex - Extract Hashtags from String

Tags: java, regex, twitter

Need to extract out hashtag Strings from a source String in Java. Any ideas / examples?

Thanks,
Sri

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is what I'm using (it handles UTF-8 tags as well, not only ASCII):

```
private static final Pattern TAG_PATTERN = 
   Pattern.compile("(?:^|\\s|[\\p{Punct}&&[^/]])(#[\\p{L}0-9-_]+)");
```

Btw, you should be able to get the hashtags from the tweet entities (`include_entities=true`)

Comment: Thanks, I'm using the Twitter Search API (JSON). Will include_entities work here?

Comment: @Srirangan I don't know, consult the documentation.

Comment: I wonder whether Twitter uses the Letter property (which is a Unicode General Category) as you have here, or whether it uses the Alphabetic property, which is a derived property that includes various diacritics and things like Roman numerals.

Comment: @tchrist twitter does not handle hashtags in scripts other than latin. So I presme they don't use the `\p{L}`

Comment: Thanks,how can get hashtag without space like instagram hashtag (#app#test) can you help me?